# Representing reverse web links graph in Scheme

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, racket, graph-theory

Hi I'm trying some exercises on Scheme and I'm able to do them using Python (using hashmaps). I have a web link graph made of website links, so that for each web site considered, I know
those websites that contain links *to* it.

I'm trying to make a function to represent the reversed web link graph. I'm trying to using lists for the representation.

If the input is `[[a, b, c], [b, c, e], [c, b, a]]` this means the site `a` is linked to *from* the sites `b` and `c`, the site `b` is linked to from `c` and `e`, and the site `c` is linked to from the sites `b` and `a`.

Thus my function should return the list: `[[a, c], [b, a, c], [c, a, b], [e, b]]`. In this case, the first element of each sublist is the source site and the tail represent all the destination sites that it links *to*.

Thanks for your help!

This is the Python code that seems to works, just for reference:

```
def reverse_linkgraph(G):
    hash_map = {}
    for u, *v in G:        
        for to in v:
            if to not in hash_map:
                hash_map[to] = set()
            hash_map[to].add(u)
    
    rev_g = []
    print(hash_map)
    for k,v in hash_map.items():       
        rev_g.append([k, *v])
    return rev_g
```

Comment: Please post your code in Scheme, Stack Overflow is not a language-translation service...

Comment: I'm not able to post an answer, as the question is closed. But I would suggest to stop trying to write Python in Scheme and leverage functional programming instead :) . 

For example, this could be solved with a Map Reduce approach:
```
```

Comment: Try:
1. Generate tuples (dst, src)
2. use group-by to join the tuples by key
3. reformat each group

Comment: the answer, if I could post it, would be: transform each `[a,b,c,d,...]` entry inside your input list into `[[b,a],[c,a],[d,a],...]`; concatenate all these resulting lists together; sort the resulting list of pairs (i.e. two-element lists) ordering them by their first component; then group together the consecutive pairs with the same first component into your desired representation.

Comment: @WillNess -- I have voted to reopen; it wasn't at all clear to me what OP was after when this post was closed, but subsequent edits have made it clear (assuming that the edits align with the non-responsive OP's intentions).

Comment: @adabsurdum the other vote is mine. :)

Comment: I think that with the format the direction is the other one [src dst1 dst2 dst3...]. But it should be better left to OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a racket equivalent to your python code:

```lisp
#lang racket

(define (reverse-linkgraph list-of-links)
  (let* ((empty-set (seteq))
         (link-table (for/fold ([table (make-immutable-hasheq)])
                               ((links list-of-links))
                       (let ((link-to (car links)))
                         (for/fold ([table table])
                                   ((link-from (cdr links)))
                           (hash-update table link-from (lambda (link-set) (set-add link-set link-to))
                                        empty-set))))))
    (hash-map link-table (lambda (from to) (cons from (set->list to))) #t)))

;;; ((a c) (b a c) (c a b) (e b))
(writeln (reverse-linkgraph '((a b c) (b c e) (c b a))))
```

The only real major difference is that it uses functional, *immutable* hash tables and sets, instead of updating mutable ones in place, and thus constructs a hash table of sets using nested [folds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) to incrementally build up the final one.

Comment: A bit late, but it was an interesting problem without an answer yet.